# How to run command prompts from a pascal program?

Tags: cmd, pascal

I need to open a file (music files specifically) using the default program for that file type from a pascal program. So far I think that the best way to do that would be to use the command line to run the command:

```
open C:/Users/defaultuser0/Music/filename.wav
```

but I'm not sure how to tell cmd to do something from within pascal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Windows, you need to use the procedure ShellExecute (and include the shellapi unit). The command would probably be

```
ShellExecute (application.handle, 'open', 
'C:/Users/defaultuser0/Music/filename.wav', nil, nil, SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

but you may have to fiddle around with this slightly. Read the documentation of the system procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In Lazarus there is an "OpenDocument" call that abstracts this functionality . On Windows it reroutes to the ShellExecuteW function, and on *nix it tries to pass it on to the relevant desktop open program (like Open/start on Windows).

The implementation is also pluggable, so if you want to open a certain document differently (e.g. PDFs directly in adobe instead of browser), you can write an intercept.

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you:

```
swapvectors;
exec('cmd','/c open "C:/Users/defaultuser0/Music/filename.wav"');
swapvectors;
```

You must use DOS unit to use that code:

```
uses dos,...;
```

(Sorry about my English)